# How do I get a function to return only the list which matches a particular string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples, match

I have the following problem; I have a tuple called `split_content`:

```html
(['@Book{Clark2003,',
  'author ,   {Eve Clark},',
  'title ,    {First Language Acquisition},',
  'publisher ,    {Cambridge University Press},',
  'address , {Cambridge, UK},',
  'year ,     2003}',
  'volume ,  10}}'],
 ['',
  '@techreport{arrow1948,',
  'author , {Arrow, Kenneth J.},',
  'title , {The possibility of a universal social welfare        function},',
  'institution , {RAND Corporation},',
  'year , {1948},',
  'number , {P-41},',
  'type , {Report}'])
```

​, which, as you can see, is already split into two sublists (before `[",'@techreport`).
I need to be able to take a string (`intext2`) and find a match in either of these two lists. E.g. `if intext2[0] = 'Clark'`. I want it to return only the first sublist, i.e. the one ending with `'volume, 10}}']`.

Now, I have written this code in order to achieve this, but it doesn't work all the time:

```html
def split_file():
    split_content = split_up()
    intext= u_input[u_input.find("(")+1:u_input.find(")")]
    intext2 = re.split('(\d+)',intext) 
    global split_content_fin
    if [intext2[0] in split_content[0]]:
        split_content_fin = split_content[0]
   
    if [intext2[0] in split_content[1]]:
        split_content_fin = split_content[1]
       
    return split_content_fin
```

Oftentimes it returns only the second substring although there is no match with `intext2[0]` at all. I have already tried list comprehensions instead of `[intext2[0]` in `split_content[0/1]]`, but to no avail. Still, I feel the issue lies just there, however, I can't find a solution. Or is it to do with it being a tuple?

Comment: Use and elif statement for the second if statement and and else statement where it 'prints("no matches found")'  for error tracking

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
split_content = (['@Book{Clark2003,',
  'author ,   {Eve Clark},',
  'title ,    {First Language Acquisition},',
  'publisher ,    {Cambridge University Press},',
  'address , {Cambridge, UK},',
  'year ,     2003}',
  'volume ,  10}}'],
 ['',
  '@techreport{arrow1948,',
  'author , {Arrow, Kenneth J.},',
  'title , {The possibility of a universal social welfare        function},',
  'institution , {RAND Corporation},',
  'year , {1948},',
  'number , {P-41},',
  'type , {Report}'])


asString_1 = ','.join(map(str,split_content[0]))
asString_2 = ','.join(map(str,split_content[1]))
aWord = 'Clark'

if(aWord in asString_1):
    print("in the first element")
elif(aWord in asString_2):
    print("in the second element")
#elif(...)
#   ...
```